# Interface Builder won't allow drag/drop of text control to window

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

Noob dumb question, no doubt -- but here it is:

Trying to tutorialize myself with the Apple "Currency Converter" tutorial for Cocoa ( http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/05View/05View.html)

Embarrassingly, I'm stuck very early on where the instructions ask me to drag-and-drop a text field onto the Currency Converter window.  When attempting to do so, I release the mouse and the text field runs animatedly back to the library palette, refusing to "stick" on the client area of the Window.

Clearly the window is readonly or lacks some state or prerequisite to accept the text field, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you're not grabbing a text CELL.

When you select the text field from the Library, check that the description is NSTextField

Comment: Turns out that's precisely where I'm screwed up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're dragging a view object and not a cell?  Double check that you're dragging `NSTextField` and not `NSTextCell`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a view to the window? Because if there is no view then you won't be able to add any controls.

Drag a "View" object over to your window.

Comment: That wasn't my problem, but it's good to know for the future.  Thanks.